# Only 1 argument passed when associated file is clicked by non Admin user

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

For some reason my Windows forms C# application is only receiving one argument when the associated file extension is used to open the app.  It's supposed to pass two, 0 being the name of the executable, and 1 being the associated file and its path.

It works perfectly fine as an administrator on the session host server I run it from. However, when I launch it as a normal user on that same session host server it only gets one argument. Why?

I'm verifying this with the following code:

```
String[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(); 
txtResult.Text = "Argument Length: " + arguments.Length + "\r\n" + arguments[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem. It had nothing to do with being an Administrator. In the case of the Administrator, apparently during troubleshooting as the admin user at some point I had manually picked the exe to associate the program using the "Open With" dialog. In the end, it was the way I had files associated using the Install Shield limited edition with Visual Studio 2013. It was the way the files were associated under the filel associations section. It was missing a %1 in the arguments field.